# Android MediaPlayer Error (-2,0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Anyone familiar with this error with Android MediaPlayer ?

```
MediaPlayer: Error (-2,0)
```

It's not documented.

Answer (score 3):

It probably comes from OpenCore, which MediaPlayer is a high level abstraction of. "-2" means that some operation was canceled.

Here the [list of error codes](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h).

```
/*
 Error due to cancellation
 */
const PVMFStatus PVMFErrCancelled = (-2);
```

Here is the [doc with the detailed code description](http://code.metager.de/source/raw/android/2.2.3/external/opencore/doc/pvmf_return_codes.pdf).

> 3.8. PVMFErrCancelled
>   This error code is returned when some old request is cancelled. In that sense this error is actually
>   an expected value and should not be treated as a fatal error.

So, you may probably ignore it, or double check how you implemented the workflow and whether it fits the expected one (you can find it in MediaPlayer class' reference).

Answer (score 0):

From [`MediaErrors.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/5f958f8/media/libstagefright/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h#29), [`include/utils/Errors.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/591cab8/libutils/include/utils/Errors.h), and [`unix_system_errors`](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) we can see that `MediaPlayer` error code `-2` can mean:

```
Signal from CodecBase to MediaCodec that the component was not found.
```